# Difference between "docker build" and "docker run" if we running dockerfile having .sh files

Tags: shell, docker

This is my **Dockerfile**

```
# This Dockerfile describes the standard way to build 
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER praveen
# Run a root to allow "rpm"
USER root
WORKDIR /root/

# Get the ACE-TAO rpm from seachange repo 
COPY TAO-1.7.7-0.x86_64.rpm  /root/TAO-1.7.7-0.x86_64.rpm

# Insatall the rpm  
RUN rpm -ivh  /root/TAO-1.7.7-0.x86_64.rpm

#Start the TAO service 
#CMD /etc/init.d/tao start

COPY namingServiceConfig.sh /
RUN /namingServiceConfig.sh

EXPOSE 13021
EXPOSE 13022
EXPOSE 13023
ENV NS_PORTS=13021,13022,13023

#ENTRYPOINT /etc/init.d/tao start && bash
```

While doing the docker build 
Whether it'll execute the shell script and reflect the changes as part images  or while running the images using **docker run**  its will  reflect the changes to container level

In my case ,I'm suspecting  that, it is executing while docker build and docker run both time

I'm using  below commands as part of building and running  via vagrant file

```
d.build_image "/vagrant/tao", args: " -t tao/basic"

 d.run "tao/basic:latest",
            args: " -t -d"\
                  " --name tao-basic"\
                  " -p 13021:13021"\
                  " -e NS_PORT=13025,13026,13027"
```

let me know, need any more information

Answer (score 3):

The Dockerfile instructions (such as `RUN` etc...) are actioned at *build* time (`docker build -t something .` etc...). Only the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions happen at *run* time (when the container is started).

In your example the shell script will get run as part of the build and whatever changes occur will be *committed* as a new layer in the image.

Comment: If i made change from  RUN to  CMD , in order to execute shell  script at run time , its giving error as Container "Restarting (x) min ago"                         can you please suggest how to process ,if i want to  run  as part run time